# How to implement Azure Push in an ASP.NET Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, notifications

I have a website created with ASP.NET. I want to use push notifications on Android and iOS to notify users about messages, requests, etc.

I tried to use Azure Push notifications by following the steps from [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started), but I do not understand how to implement Azure Push into my project.

How can I implement Azure Push in my ASP.NET project?

Comment: What steps of the tutorial caused problems for you?

Comment: You need to provide more details on how far you got and what problems you saw for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: I did all the steps in this link successful, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started but I don't know what the next or how I will used in my c# projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did all the steps in this link successful, learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/… but I don't know what the next or how I will used in my c# projects

Based on your description, you have successfully created the Azure Notification Hub and created your project for refreshing the GCM token and register it with Azure Notification Hub. For pushing notifications to the client users via Azure Notification Hubs in your ASP.NET project, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-gcm-android-push-to-user-google-notification).